# Google map is being loaded in the background but not showing on the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, google-maps

I have a custom map that I stylized and at one time it worked just fine but now it won't show up for some reason. I can use firebug and find the Div that is supposed to load the map and it shows the map code being inserted. But the problem is something is blocking it from being shown.

Here is the javascript for the creation and styling of the map..

```
function initialize() {



        var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(44.98730,   -93.27591);

        var image = '../wp-content/uploads/2013/11/mapMarker.png';

        var styles = [
            {
                featureType: "landscape.natural",
                                    elementType: 'geometry', 
                stylers: [
                    { color: '#56595c' }        
                ]
            },
                            {
                featureType: "landscape.man_made",
                                    elementType: 'geometry', 
                stylers: [
                    { color: '#56595c' } 
                ]
            },
                            {
                featureType: "road.highway",
                                    elementType: 'geometry.stroke', 
                stylers: [
                    { color: '#b2bb1c' },
                                            { weight: '1' }
                ]
            },
                            {
            featureType: "road.highway",
                                    elementType: 'geometry.fill', 
                stylers: [
                    { color: '#56595c' } 
                ]
            },
                            {  
                featureType: 'road.local',  
                elementType: 'geometry.stroke',  
                stylers: [  
                    { color: '#b2bb1c' },
                                            { weight: '1' }

                ]  
            } ,
                            {
            featureType: "road.local",
                                    elementType: 'geometry.fill', 
                stylers: [
                    { color: '#56595c' } 
                ]
            },
                            {

                featureType: "road.arterial",
                elementType: "geometry.stroke",
                stylers: [
                    { color: '#b2bb1c' },
                                            { weight: '1' }
                ]
            },
                           {
            featureType: "road.arterial",
                                    elementType: 'geometry.fill', 
                stylers: [
                    { color: '#56595c' } 
                ]
            },
                                                           {
            featureType: "road.arterial",
                                    elementType: 'geometry.fill', 
                stylers: [
                    { color: '#56595c' } 
                ]
            },
                            {
                featureType: "poi", 
                elementType: 'geometry',
                stylers: [
                    { color: '#6e7073' }
                ]
            },
                            {
                featureType: "water", 
                elementType: 'geometry',
                stylers: [
                    { color: '#a2a5a9' }
                ]
            }
        ];

        var myOptions = {
            zoom: 16,
            center: latlng,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
            disableDefaultUI: true,
            styles: styles
        };

        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), myOptions);       
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          position: latlng,
          map: map,
          icon: image
        });


    }
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

I know this is working because if I use firebug and clear out the embedded style for "position: relative;" you can partially see the map. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you set the height and width CSS on the map element?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to force refreshing like this?

```
google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');
```

Answer (score 0):

Please refer the link.

http://jsfiddle.net/UeP2f/

```
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 12,
    center: latlog,
    mapTypeControlOptions: {
      mapTypeIds: [google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP, MY_MAPTYPE_ID]
    },
    mapTypeId: MY_MAPTYPE_ID
  };

  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'),
      mapOptions);

  var styledMapOptions = {
    name: 'Custom Style'
  };

  var customMapType = new google.maps.StyledMapType(featureOpts, styledMapOptions);

  map.mapTypes.set(MY_MAPTYPE_ID, customMapType);
```